# How do I stop Apple VoiceOver double-reading headings with multiple elements?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

If I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>
      Buy our awesome product!
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

... Apple VoiceOver will say:

*"heading level 2, Buy our awesome product"*

Which is great, and expected.

However, if I change it to this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>
      Buy our <i>awesome</i> product!
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apple VoiceOver will say:

*"heading level 2, 3 items, Buy our... awesome... product... Buy our... awesome... product"*

(adds "3 items", pauses between elements, and critically, **repeats the heading**)

I'm expecting VoiceOver to just say it exactly the same way as it does without the italics.

Of course I'd love to keep it from saying "3 items" and remove the pauses, but **the main concern is that it repeats the heading**. I've tried using <span>, using classes, and enclosing everything in a <div> as others have suggested on similar questions, but nothing I've tried so far seems to prevent the repeating. I feel like I must be missing something simple, right? Or is there really no way to style parts of a heading without glitching VoiceOver?

Possibly relevant or helpful, I've discovered this issue only seems to come up for headings. If I run VoiceOver on the following code, it's just read once as if the italics or separate elements weren't there at all:

```
<p>
  Buy our <i>awesome</i> product!
</p>
```

This issue occurs for me on both Chrome and Safari. I have not tested other browsers.

If at all possible I would prefer an HTML/CSS solution and avoid using a javascript hack, as I am not a javascript pro.

Disclosures:

- Yes, I'm using styling beyond `<i>` to specifically style certain elements of my headings, but the above is a much simpler example and produces the same results.
- My problem page is in fact running some scripts like Google Tag Manager and jquery, but even if I create a completely naked test page with the above HTML I get exactly the same results.

Comment: Is it on iOS, on MacOS, or both ? You can try role=heading on the h2, role=none on the i, or role=text on the h2, the i, or a new span under the h2. Tell if any of these works so that I can post a real answer. But you are right, you shouldn't have to do a hack like this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a VoiceOver bug, and not one that is easy to work around.

Last year, I ran various [test cases with VoiceOver](https://lab.dotjay.com/tests/screen-readers/voiceover-text-breaks-workarounds/) and found that the only approach that avoids the experience you describe in VoiceOver was to use `role="text"`. This would stop VoiceOver from treating each child element as a separate heading as shown in [this demo and explanation by Patrick H Lauke on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nkcnm7xZZP4). For example:

```
<h2><span role="text"><span style="display: block;color: red;">This is styled text</span> and this is a new line</span></h2>
```

When `role="text"` (unofficial spec) is applied to a container element, it would force VoiceOver to recalculate the accessible name of the heading element, reducing it to a single element. This worked on macOS and iOS.

I also tested using `aria-label` to try to hack around these issues in VoiceOver, but found no suitable solution.

However, it seems that VoiceOver now has a more consistent experience across each of the techniques I tested. While VoiceOver now reads the headings as a single announcement, it also always announces that there are multiple items within the element. I'm in the process of testing this further.

You may like to try one of the techniques I used in [my test cases](https://lab.dotjay.com/tests/screen-readers/voiceover-text-breaks-workarounds/), but use with caution. However, it may be that there is now nothing you can use as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, kind of a hack I guess, but this is what ended up working for me:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2 aria-label="Buy our awesome product!">
      <span aria-hidden="true">
        Buy our <i>awesome</i> product!
      </span>
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```